# Hide default Android Soft-input in EditText doesn't works

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have try to hide the default soft-input keyboard with

```
  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

but when I click the EditText the keyboard appears again

I have tried also

```
input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

and

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

with no result, 
the keyboard appears always when I click the EditText.

If I set inputType null, the keybard doesn't appear but the editText became unusable since I cannot select or move the cursor anymore nor copy-paste anything

Any solution?

Comment: So if I get you correct you don't want keyboard to appear ever?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Exactly. I have a custom keyboard, and don't want keyboard to appear ever but I want that the EditText cursor react normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want that keyboard appears ever, use this code:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

In this way the android soft keyboard will be always hidden, and you can use the cursor, selection copy-paste etc. normally.

Answer (score 0):

Setting no extract ui won't work, that means not to show that large fullscreen view that phones show in landscape.  The keyboard will still appear.

There is no api to permanently turn off the keyboard.  If you want to do it, I'd use android:editable=false, then you'll have to handle all of the setting of text yourself (since you aren't using a real input method).

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

where **editText** is your EditText component's name.